# How to add unmanaged C++ dll into a Silverlight 5 project

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight-5.0

I need to use a my own unmanaged C++ dll into Silverlight 5 project.

As I am able to use it using dllImport i.e.

```
   [DllImport(@"D:\myLib\Debug\myLib.dll")]
    static extern int add(IntPtr ptr);
```

It works fine as I metioned a absoulte path in DllImport. But my problem is, I want to use the relative path.

As I need to add unmanaged C++ dll in my silverlight 5 project and specify path from there.
I am investigating from last two days I did not find any solution for this issue.

Only I found one related link mentioned below but it also does not help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.dllimportattribute.aspx

As It suggest how to embed your unmanaged dll into managed assembly.
I tried this approach but I am getting "BadImageException".

Please suggest to over come to this issue as it is really urgent for me.

Thanks,

Vipin

Comment: DllImportAttribute **won't embed an unmanaged library** into your Silverlight application (by the way absolutetly avoid that kind of absolute paths). It just add a **reference to that library** but it must be **downloaded and installed separately**.

Comment: Is your SL5 app running with elevated permissions?  If not, I wouldn't expect to be able to use an unmanaged DLL.

Comment: The [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) page has a 'Remarks' section that outlines the possible reasons you could receive this error.  I would go through them and see if that helps resolve the issue.

Comment: The BadImageFormatException is probably a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. Make sure the Silverlight setup is running with the same bitness as the native DLL.

Answer (score 1):

When Silverlight 5 Release Candidate was made public, I created some support methods for handling this issue of bundling unmanaged non-system DLL:s with your Silverlight 5 RC application. The solution is still valid, since Microsoft did not add any support to deal with the bundling issue in Silverlight 5 RTM.

What I do is basically to bundle the unmanaged DLL as a resource file. Through a helper method manually invoked e.g. in the application startup event handler the resource is copied to a predefined location on disk. This location is then also included in the system PATH during execution.

Elevated trust is required (of course).

More details on this solution can be found in [this](http://cureos.blogspot.com/2011/09/pinvoke-bundling-native-dlls-in.html) blog post.

All code associated with this solution, including sample tests, can be found on [Github](https://github.com/cureos/nativedll).

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comment below by Simon Mourier, one option would also be to load into memory (and release upon application exit) the unmanaged DLL by calling the *Kernel32* [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function after the DLL has been unpacked from the resources. This approach for Silverlight is described in more detail in [this](http://thebytekitchen.com/2012/03/15/pinvoking-directx-from-silverlight/) blog post.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid to change the system PATH if you use the LoadLibrary function (since you do have a valid path) just before any P/Invoke call. Once a DLL is loaded in the process, DllImport should succeed. It used to work on standard .NET, I have not tested it in SL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx

Comment: Many thanks for the comment, @SimonMourier. I have not thought about this option, but it seems doable. Simple Googling showed that someone else has actually succeeded with this approach in SL. I will update the answer with this new information.